# Why do I have extraneous objects in my Core Data object?

Tags: core-data, xcode4.5

I have an app which uses Core Data.  I have defined the Entities with their respective attributes several times.  Now, I pretty much have it finalized, looking like this:
[image]

I deleted the old sqlite d/b, re-ran the program which creates a new Sqlite d/b, and it looks like this (using SQLite Database Browser).  The areas highlighted in yellow are the ones that don't belong there (IMHO)... how do I clear the old junk out of there when the Sqlite d/b is re-built from Core Data?

[image]

Comment: if you aren't sure about the db, remove the app from the simulator or device and run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motivation is quite simple.

When you use **entity inheritance**, Core Data, under the hood, creates a (relational) table that has all the properties for the parent entity as well as its child (or children).

Although this feature is very useful, you should be aware of such a mechanism to avoid performance penalties.

Anyway, you should not work with the db created for you. You should think only in terms of object graph. You will simplify your life.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I only look at the d/b so I can see what the results of my testing are... but, thanks for the suggestions anyway. But the question still is: what's all the extra "stuff" in the d/b tables?

Comment: @spokane-dude Did you try to remove the app? Anyway in ZCLIENTINFO table, the highlighted columns are correct. They are there since *AppointmentInfo* "extends" *ClientInfo*.

Comment: Ahhh... that explains it... thank you... I'll reset the simulator and see what happens...thanks again...

Comment: @spokane-dude You're welcome. Maybe I didn't explain it in my answer.. ;)